# MYSQL find results with most amount of column matches

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a good way of querying a table (providing the values for a number of columns) ordering the results with the best matches first?

Table would look like this:

```
cat id | feature a | feature b | feature c
1      | NULL      | 1         | 2
2      | 1         | 2         | NULL
3      | 3         | 1         | 3
```

Say I have values 1/2/3 for features a/b/c and I'm looking for the nearest match, I would expect the results to be topped by category 2 as this has the most matches.

Nearest I can find is this answer but it doesn't work for some reason:
[MySQL matching 2 out of 5 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109375/mysql-matching-2-out-of-5-fields)

This is a similar question but the answer is for Oracle:
[SQL - Return rows with most column matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437338/sql-return-rows-with-most-column-matches)

Here's my full query as it stands:

```
$query_string = "SELECT cat_id FROM categories ORDER BY (";
if ($head_type > 0) { $string_array[] = "(cat_code_head_type = " . (int)$head_type . ")"; }
if ($material > 0) { $string_array[] = "(cat_code_material = " . (int)$material . ")"; }
if ($finish > 0) { $string_array[] = "(cat_code_finish = " . (int)$finish . ")"; }
if ($recess > 0) { $string_array[] = "(cat_code_recess = " . (int)$recess . ")"; }
if ($thread > 0) { $string_array[] = "(cat_code_thread = " . (int)$thread . ")"; }
$query_string .= implode(" + ", $string_array);
$query_string .= ") DESC";
```

Ending up like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
ORDER BY ((cat_code_head_type = ?) + (cat_code_material = ?) + (cat_code_finish = ?) + (cat_code_recess = ?) + (cat_code_thread = ?)) DESC
```

I'm not even sure if you can order by the addition of matching expressions?

Comment: Why don't you just post your full query?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, but it *sounds* like one symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: What if you have another row: `NULL | 2 | 3`

Comment: If you have another row NULL | 2 | 3 then both/either could be the top result

Comment: @cdaiga does that make it clearer? Apologies for the fuzzy question.

Comment: @Strawberry does that make it clearer? Apologies for the fuzzy question.

Comment: This feels like a very poorly designed table and it's why you are having such a hard time solving this query. Perhaps a table like ` cat_id | col_number | value ` would make more sense. Then it's just a matter of aggregating and selecting the matching cat_id. Nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. Admittedly it's a bit backwards! The column values currently relate to values in other tables with further feature information for each category however the features are not mandatory so can be NULL. All this query is doing is looking for the most likely category match when you know a random set of features.